# Validation time format using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to validate the time format. Below is my code.

```
x = re.search('([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2})','7:30')
x.string
'7:30' (which is true)
```

But

```
x = re.search('([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2})','700:30')
x.string
'700:30'
```

Should result in nonetype but showing the value)

Answer (score -2):

The second example is matching the text `00:30`. You should rather use the function `re.match`.

```py
x = re.match('([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2})','7:30')
print(x)

x = re.match('([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2})','700:30')
print(x)
```

output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='7:30'>
None
```

Comment: `re.match` does not force matching the entire string and `re.match('([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{2})','700:30')` will also validate `7:200000000`

Comment: re.fullmatch() works.